# Multiple connection string in azure mobile service

Tags: azure-mobile-services

We have different database as per client but all SP's and tables schema are same for all.

How to connect azure mobile service base on client?

Option:

1. publish service as per client, so number of client is equal to services.
2. put all connection string in config file. Read header value and pick connection accordingly.
3. any other option, do you know.

1st option is not feasible for us. because need publish code on all site for single change.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really use Azure Mobile Services for this.  Azure Mobile Services is pretty much designed around a single database per service.  I'd suggest switching over to Azure App Service.   If you just need database access, you can set up a REST endpoint that provides the necessary access but looking up your connection strings on a per-authenticated user.  You might want to use a schema per client instead to reduce the number of connection strings you have.

Short version: Look at the design of your service to reduce the number of SQL connection strings you are using.  An ideal number is 1.

Comment: I have to use this mobile app backend for offline sync with ios core data. and my requirments are to connect to different database using single mobile app backend service at runtime. how can i do this?

Comment: You can't.  Your requirements are incompatible with the SDKs that are available.